# jQuery select поиск по содержимому. как вернуть начальное состояние элемента?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

Есть у меня select на странице, в котором очень много элементов. Я реализовал это следующим образом

[image: Компонент]

```js
//jQuery extension method:
jQuery.fn.filterByText = function (textbox) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var select = this;
        var options = [];
        $(select).find('option').each(function () {
            options.push({
                value: $(this).val(),
                text: $(this).text()
            });
        });
        $(select).data('options', options);

        $(textbox).bind('change keyup', function () {
            var options = $(select).empty().data('options');
            var search = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
            if (search.length < 2)
                return;
            var regex = new RegExp(search, "gi");

            $.each(options, function (i) {
                var option = options[i];
                if (option.text.match(regex) !== null) {
                    $(select).append(
                        $('<option>').text(option.text).val(option.value)
                    );
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
```

**Первая проблема** в том, что список не возвращается в начальное состояние при стирании текста в строке поиска (элемент над select)

**Вторая проблема** в том, что если ввести точное название и останется только один элемент, то даже если его выбрать, валидация говорит, что элемент не выбран (т.е. надо обязательно выбирать хотябы из двух)

**Есть ли какие либо варианты исправить данные проблемы?**

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется Вы делаете, то что уже сделано до Вас=) Попробуйте использовать библиотеку selectize. (https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/)

Там как раз то что Вам нужно, и поиск по элементам тоже.

Comment: Ограничен в использовании доп библиотек, но спасибо за наводку :)